# Inner join return only the first matching Row

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I've looked everywhere in the site and over google and did not found the answer I was looking for, I have 2 tables with specific info on each and the report gives duplicates
I would need to get the name, the feedback ID and the site with a maximum of 1 feedback ID.

Here are my 2 tables

Table:  **Feedback**

```
userID              | ID 
john.smith          |1
george.wilson       |2
justin.example      |3
justin.example      |4
juliana.something   |5
george.wilson       |6
```

Table:  **Users** (other info on this table give a reason for the duplicates )

```
UserID              |Site
george.wilson       |location 1
george.wilson       |location 1
george.wilson       |location 1
john.smith          |Location 2
john.smith          |Location 2
juliana.something   |Location 3
justin.example      |Location 4
justin.example      |Location 4
```

**Current Query**

```
SELECT feedback.userID,  feedback.id, Users.Site        
FROM feedback       
INNER JOIN users ON     
feedback.userID = users.userid      
WHERE feedback.userID <> 'x'
```

**Current result**

```
UserID              |ID | Sites
john.smith          |1  |Location 2
john.smith          |1  |Location 2
george.wilson       |2  |location 1
george.wilson       |2  |location 1
george.wilson       |2  |location 1
justin.example      |3  |Location 4
justin.example      |3  |Location 4
justin.example      |4  |Location 4
justin.example      |4  |Location 4
juliana.something   |5  |Location 3
george.wilson       |6  |location 1
george.wilson       |6  |location 1
george.wilson       |6  |location 1
```

**Expected results**

```
UserID              |ID | Sites
john.smith          |1  |Location 2
george.wilson       |2  |location 1
justin.example      |3  |Location 4
justin.example      |4  |Location 4
juliana.something   |5  |Location 3
george.wilson       |6  |location 1
```

My query has been minimize, more content is required but the error comes from my "inner join" users, can anywone help me with this issue please? ( i am using My Sql Workbench 6.0 )
thank you in advance!

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT feedback.userID,  feedback.id, Users.Site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the `users` table with a query on `feedback`, using a `limit` clause to limit the nuber of rows:

```
SELECT     f.userID, f.id, u.site
FROM       feedback f
INNER JOIN (SELECT   userID, site
            FROM     users
            ORDER BY site DESC
            LIMIT    1) u ON g.userID = u.userID
WHERE      f.userID <> 'x'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping, i tried and i am sure it's only 1 small step away from success with this query i get 0 row returned, while without joining my sites and the users table i get 188 row ( the result expected but with sites hehe) also in your query you added a g.userID what does it refer to?  thank you once again.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the duplicated data.  SQL doesn't know or care why it's been duplicated in the table, it's just going to return everything that matches your query exactly.  It's a really simple query so just add DISTINCT to eliminate the duplicate rows without any extra weird joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT feedback.userID,  feedback.id, users.Site
FROM feedback, users
WHERE feedback.userID = users.userid      
AND feedback.userID <> 'x'
```

Comment: With the distinct i get only 88 rows while i should get 188 row returned, i've tried that already but it filter more stuff that it should, i don't know what was removed, it's a good idea, but my query is alot bigger and looks like it find duplicates info and not duplicate row. my real query looks through 5 different tables... is there a way to point a distinct to only 1 column of 1 table, I.E. my query without distinct gives me 2820 rows, if after my result it could just filter this data and keep only 1 of each feedback.ID that would do the trick.